# Apache Drill 1.8 UI doesn't display Hive join query results

Tags: exception, join, hive, apache-drill

I am using Apache Drill 1.8.0 on AWS EMR and joining two hive tables. Below is sample query. This working fine in Drill CLI but giving below error after running few minutes. If i try simple select query (select t1.col from hive.table t1) it works fine in both Drill CLI and UI. Only problem with join query.

If i cancel the join query from background, it displays results in UI. This is very strange situation.

**Join Query**:

```
select t1.col FROM hive.table1 as t1 join hive.table2 as t2 on t1.col = t2.col limit 1000;
```

**Error**:

> Query Failed: An Error Occurred
>   org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: RpcException: Data not accepted downstream. Fragment 1:4 [Error Id: 0b5ed2db-3653-4e3a-9c92-d0a6cd69b66e on ip-172-31-16-222.us-west-2.compute.internal:31010]